# How to add custom color to menu in tab - Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to add custom color to menu on tabs , I want color to fill the entire menu , currently this menu is in tab and I wanted a custom color to be added on top of it.

[current code](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-muho2n?file=/example.js)

if you see the above code default colors like red and orange works fine but when i try to add a custom color the entire menu turns black. how i can resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is:

Semantic UI adds a class to the menu with the "color-name" that is passed to `color` prop. See the image below when we pass a custom color instead of a "pre-defined color class"
[image]

One of the **Solution(s):**

`className` attribute to menu props and define the custom css for that className.
[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-txt65f?file=/index.scss)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't pass any `color` into the `<Tab />` component.

The console returns a warning:

> expected one of ["red","orange","yellow","olive","green","teal","blue","violet","purple","pink","brown","grey","black"].

My suggestion is the following:

1. Use `CSS` to target the the `background-color` to make it transparent
2. Apply your own `background-color` by styling the component

```css
.ui.inverted.menu {
    background: transparent;
}
```

```js
        <Tab
          menu={{ color, inverted: true, attached: false, tabular: false }}
          panes={panes}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: color
          }}
        />
```

Here's a [fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-lxy60r)